# Marshalling Undetermined data type

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

With a custom `Marshaller` I try to map a DynamoDB query to an object

```
class ownObject {
  private int myInteger;

  @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = MasrshallAsInteger.class)
  @DynamoDBAttribute      
  public int getMyInteger {
    return myInteger;
  }

  public void setMyInteger(int newint) {
    myInteger = newint;
  }
}
```

Since the value `myInteger` in the db has both types `String` and `Number`, the SDK throws the Exception: **"Expected S in value {N:123,}"** if I use the marshaller and **"Expected N in value {S:123,}"** on an other object if I don't .

Is there any way to force the DynamoDB to use a custom marshaller and parse the value of the Key as String? Or is there any other way to parse a undetermined type of data but using `PaginatedQueryList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use the Document SDK to paginate, parse your items into Item objects, paginate, and then convert those Items to your domain.

```
Table table = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(new DefaultCredentialsProviderChain()).getTable("ownObject");
for (Item item : table.scan()) {
    //convert item to your domain object here
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Even if the Document API isn't directly available for Android. I have to consider to import the Java SDK.